# asp.net core 2 angular app looking for .component.html files in wrong place

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, single-page-application

I have a ASP.net core 2 web app using angular 4 within a Visual Studio 2017 project, I used the Angular SPA template in Visual Studio to create this.

Whilst it has been working OK previously, now there is a problem in that when I run the app the angular app doesn't work. In Chrome dev tools I can see things like :
    GET http://localhost:65159/home.component.html 404 (Not Found)

It is looking for .component.html files in the wrong place and getting back 404 errors.

I don't know why it's suddenly started doing this.

Comment: Which selector you are mentioned in `index.cshtml`  
`<app>...</app>` ?

Comment: It is :   <app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

Comment: You are getting blank page with out any errors?

Comment: The web page just shows "Loading..." in the place where the angular app should render, no errors on the web page itself. As a work around I can copy all .component.html and .component.css files that are in /ClientApp/app/Components into /wwwroot to get it to work.